# запуск функции php из javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[песочница](https://wtools.io/ru/php-sandbox/b58x)

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на отрисованный span вызывалась php функция test() и снизу появлялся новый блок, но при выполнении кода функция test() выполняется сразу на этапе отрисовки страницы и, как следствие, новый блок появляется так же сразу, а не при нажатии на span. Я так понимаю это нормальное поведение - все функции php в файле php срабатывают сверху вниз при отрисовки страницы? Но можно ли как-то выполнить нужную мне задачу? Чтобы из сформированного мною html кода по клику вызывалась функция php.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: Если вы хотите добавить событие клика на DOM элемент браузера это необходимо делать средствами javascript а не php, тогда функция будет выполняться именно при клике. Если же вам нужны данные от сервера, которые получает php вы можете запросить их через AJAX запрос который также пропишите в объявленном событии клика через javascript.